# Expected value of $1/X$.

Tags: probability

Given a random variable $X$ with probability density function $$f(x)=\frac5{x^6}\mathbf 1_{\{x>1\}}$$
I am trying to find the mean of $1/X$. After making the transformation I find that $f(1/x)=5x^4$. So far I've come up with only whole numbers but the answer is supposed to be a fraction.

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean that $f(x)=5/x^6$ is the pdf?

Comment: Your transformation is fine, but what happened to the indicator function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
<1/x>=\int_1^\infty dx (1/x)5/x^6=5\int_1^\infty dx\frac{1}{x^7}=\frac{5}{6}\ .
$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}\Bbb E\left[\frac1X\right]&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac1xf(x)d x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac1x\cdot \frac5{x^6}\mathbf 1_{\{x>1\}}dx=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{5}{x^7}dx\\[0.2cm]&=\left[\frac5{-6x^6}\right]^{+\infty}_1=0-\frac{5}{-6}=\frac56\end{align}